# Class asks me to give self for Naive Bayes Model python

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, prediction, naivebayes

I try to use the following code but when I try to use fit function with my X_train and y_train 
I get the following error

`fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I do not know much about classes but I know it should not be asking me the self. I found somethings about instantiation but could not figure it out.

```
class BernoulliNB(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha=1.0):
        self.alpha = alpha

    def fit(self, X, y):
        count_sample = X.shape[0]
        # group by class
        separated = [[x for x, t in zip(X, y) if t == c] for c in np.unique(y)]
        # class prior
        self.class_log_prior_ = [np.log(len(i) / count_sample) for i in separated]
        # count of each word
        count = np.array([np.array(i).sum(axis=0) for i in separated]) + self.alpha

        smoothing = 2 * self.alpha
        # number of documents in each class + smoothing
        n_doc = np.array([len(i) + smoothing for i in separated])
        print(n_doc)

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(self.predict_log_proba(X), axis=1)
```

when i try

```
b = BernoulliNB() 
b.fit(b, X_train,y_train)
```

this time i receive

```
fit() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Then I changed it to

```
BernoulliNB().fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but this time this error occures

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I'm guessing you used `BernoulliNB.fit()`? try `BernoulliNB().fit()`

Comment: You will need to provide more context. Can you give a sample of the code around the  function call ?

Comment: @ValentinM. can you give me more detail

Comment: @AliEnverArslan What are the 5 lines above and 5 lines bellow `BernoulliNB().fit(X_train,y_train)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `BernoulliNB.fit(...)` instead of

```py
b = BernoulliNB()
b.fit(...)
```

---

In the code sample above, `b` is an *instance* of `BernoulliNB`, and so pass itself as `self`.

You could also use

```py
b = BernoulliNB()
BernoulliNB.fit(b,...)
```

or (as suggested by Guy)

```py
BernoulliNB().fit(...)
```